# does the EVGA 02G-P3-1568-KR GeForce GTX 560 Ti (Fermi) support 3 monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a `EVGA 02G-P3-1568-KR GeForce GTX 560 Ti (Fermi) 2GB 256-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 2.0 x16 HDCP Ready SLI Support Video Card`. It has 1 `hdmi` and 2 `dvi`, will it support 3 monitors? I am currently using 2 monitors with `dvi`.

Can i plug a third monitor into the `hdmi` port and have 3 functioning?

Thanks

Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From everything I can dig up, the card only supports a total of two video outputs total... and the HDMI actually shares the output of one of the DVI.  Some have had success adding a [Triple Head 2 Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/displayport/) module for more than 2 displays with this card.

Comment: Never mind, i think i will just buy another card and sli, and use four. I have 4 monitors, but was hoping to be able to do 3 while i waited for my second card. Thanks

Comment: Most of them are user experience based from forums... there are a lot in the EVGA forums like this one http://www.evga.com/forums/fb.ashx?m=1584208

Comment: And this http://www.evga.com/forums/fb.ashx?m=1458437 it is an issue/feature that spans more than just the 560's... or the 500's for that matter.